# Next js api not works on netlify

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js, netlify

I have a web application for next js. I want to put it on netlify, but when I do this, the api stops working for me, although everything worked fine on vercel. When i call api a get 404 error[image]

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "devhub-website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "export": "next export"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.0",
    "next": "9.5.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.0.27",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.46",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: Pls share your package.json for frontend and backend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `next export` to deploy in Netlify, the API routes do not work. When we build with `next export`, this warning shows in the terminal:

> Statically exporting a Next.js application via `next export` disables
> API routes. This command is meant for static-only hosts, and is not
> necessary to make your application static.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the target to serverless in `next.config.js`

The Next.js serverless target outputs Serverless functions from pages.

```
module.exports = {
  target: "serverless",
};
```